# re.search always returns None

Tags: python, python-re

```
temp = b'pOSt /key/key'
print(type(re.search(temp, b'POST', re.IGNORECASE)))
```

```
<class 'NoneType'>
```

The following code always returns none. Not sure what is wrong. I want to check whether does the binary contains the word 'POST'.

Comment: Did you check the docs? Specifically of [`re.search(pattern, string, flags=0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) (before clicking, look at the arguments' names)

Answer (score 2):

[`search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) arguments are switched (first is pattern then the string):

```
import re

temp = b'pOSt /key/key'
m = re.search(b'POST', temp, re.IGNORECASE)

# b'pOSt'
print(m[0])
```